# Stored Procedure calling problems

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have stored procedure `A` which updates 2 tables and executes a second stored procedure `B` in a different database. All code is wrapped in a transaction. However the database that holds stored proc `B` keeps getting locked in an uncommitted transaction. Why?

I think the code is correct. Also do you think there is any further considerations I should be thinking about running the following code:

`@Success` is an output from stored procedure `B`

```
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION 

        Update tblTableA set varA = @ValueA

        Update tblTableB set varB = @ValueB

        EXEC Database2.schema.StoredprocB @ValueC, @Success

                    SELECT  @Success                                                        

        IF @Success = 1
            ROLLBACK 
        ELSE
            COMMIT 

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

    ROLLBACK 
    SET @Success = 1

END CATCH
```

Comment: Is StoredProcB doing anything complex? Is it possible that another procedure or process is changing the data that StoredProcB is using?

Comment: May not be related, but if `@Success` is meant to be set by `StoredProcB`, it has to be marked as `OUTPUT` both in `StoredProcB`s parameter declarations, *and* in the `EXEC` line (which it isn't in the code you've shown)

Comment: Is that B database at the same server/instance A database? Otherwise you ill need a distributed transaction

Comment: jean - Yes its on the same instance.

Comment: In general if SPB is working with different objects that's no problem. Please post SPB source and check if that updates are not firing triggers. For further investigation verify what locks (granularity, exclusivity, object) are issued when SPA and SPB executes.